# etymology: drag (clothing)

Tags: etymology

I've seen conflicting accounts as the etymology of 'drag' (as in: drag queen).

the first being acronymical of "Dressed as A Girl".

the second as:

> One suggested etymological root is 19th-century theatre slang, from the sensation of long skirts trailing on the floor. -*Wikipedia*

Any conclusive answers as to the etymology of drag?~

Comment: Don't be a drag. You likely found the inconclusive answers yourself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OED marks this as *slang*:

> **3.g.** Feminine attire worn by a man; also, a party or dance attended by men wearing feminine attire; hence *gen.,* clothes, clothing. *slang.*
>
> > 1870  *Reynolds's Newsp.* 29 May 5/5   We shall come in drag.
> > 1927   *Sunday Express* 13 Feb. 5/5   A drag is a rowdy party attended by abnormal men dressed in scanty feminine garments, singing jazz songs in high falsetto voices.

Slang rarely has any etymology. It may sometimes be possible to deduce how a word has been adopted into its slang use, and in this case it would appear that *drag* as a style of dress was derived from the party at which it was worn. Or, possibly, the other way round.

> **7.h.** A slow type of dance, or the music for this; also (*slang*), a dancing party. *U.S.*
>
> > 1901   Joplin & Hayden (*title of song*)    Sun Flower Slow Drag.

The "slow dance" lends credence to the long skirts dragging on the floor mentioned in the question; it's likely that in 1870 the "feminine attire" would have included long skirts. By 1927 *drag* clothing appears to have entered the Charleston era and become "scanty", allowing the dancing party to become "rowdy".